# Why cant pointer type be inferred based upon the type of variable it points to?

Tags: c, pointers

Question: Is there any particular reason that if the complier knew an `int` goes into an address, then it cant remember that an `int` is there when reading?

1. As I understand, `line 0` tells the compiler to allocate 16 bits for whatever value will be placed there upon assignment in `line 3`.
2. And I understand that one of the reasons for declaring the pointer type at `line 1` is to tell the compiler how many bytes to read when dereferencing the pointer `p` with `*p` on `line 6`.

```
    0:    int i;
    1:    int *p;
    2:
    3:    i = 5;
    4:    p = &i;
    5:
    6:    printf("%d",*p);
```

For simplicity, using bit-width of 8 in mem table.
Say `i` is written at 0x04 and `p` is written at 0x02.

```
  addr | storedVal  
 -----------------
  0x01 |           
  0x02 | 00000100 
  0x03 |          
  0x04 | 00000000 
  0x05 | 00000101
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"it cant remember that an int is there when reading?"*? `printf` is just a function, it doesn't get special treatment by the compiler

Comment: Are you asking about the ability to infer the type at compile time? It's possible in principle, just doesn't happen to be part of C's design.  Or at run time? Pointers would require additional memory to store the type of what's pointed to, and the language designers didn't want to impose that overhead since it's usually not needed.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think this is what I meant to ask. Not so much about inference but rather only having to declare a type once if the pointer variable and int variable will be associated with one another on `line 4`. But I'm so new to C that I may not be educated enough to really articulate what I'm confused about

Comment: @Justin What the compiler "remembers" is its own business. To you, what matters is that the compiled code behaves "as if" it went through the steps you wrote. For example, the compiler can optimize the entire code you posted as just `printf("%d",5);`, see e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/za8EWK).

Comment: To add to Nate's comment, "need" is relative. Knowing the type at run-type is a convenience that Rubyists and Pythonistas love, but pay _heavily_ in speed and memory use. C is as close to assembly as a higher-level programming language can be; you get speed, you get small memory footprint, but at the cost of having to do everything yourself. For most purposes, C (and even C++) should be used for memory/time-critical portions, and leave the non-critical parts to more comfortable languages (developer time is more expensive than CPU time).

Comment: thanks @dxiv for that resource. this is awesome

Comment: @Amadan OTOH, there is only relatively modest RTI overheads in .NET or even Java (which compiles to IL and can JIT relatively handily) .. Ruby and Python are “dog slow” due to the languages’ dynamic nature, not the inherent RTI support. Static languages can support various levels of type inference and variations on generics/templates/etc. to push through types. (That is, there are much better comparisons to make.)

Comment: While it’s still unfair to compare GC and non-GC designs in certain time/memory critical applications, at least that starts to get down to the relevant details (and holds it _separate_ from the type system used). Also consider Rust, etc.

Comment: @user2864740 I am not saying it is the only factor, but it certainly contributes. I don't see how it is controversial that copying 8 bytes (size of double in C or Java) is faster than copying 24 (size of equivalent data in Python), even if we ignore unboxing/boxing. AFAIK Java slows down considerably if you use `Integer` (a value with run-time type information attached, like any value in Python) instead of `int` (a primitive, with no extras, like any type in C). In C it takes 9 bytes to hold an empty string (NUL and a pointer to it), in Python — 49. I don't know Rust, can't consider it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be if the language allowed it; in C++, you could delay the declaration of `p` until the point of assignment and just do:

```
auto p = &i;
```

and it would infer that `p` is an `int*`. C doesn't do that though. It has no syntactic facility for deriving the type of an object, so you need to declare the type explicitly.

If you're talking about `printf`, `printf` is a varargs function; it doesn't know the types of the variables passed to it (some compilers special case it for checks at compile time, but that's an implementation detail, not a language guarantee; at runtime it doesn't know). It only knows to look for an `int` because the `%d` placeholder told it to check for that (and no pointers are involved inside `printf`; it was passed the raw `int` read from the pointer, not a pointer to the `int`).

Answer (score 1):

It could, I mean c++ repurposes the auto keyword for this, but C was designed as a systems programming language and being able to write to memory as one type and read as another is very natural in that space (Implementation defined obviously, but just what about systems programming is not?).

Sometimes it is the underlying hardware that is writing to a memory region (array of bytes) and you want to read the word at offset 0x16 as an int32, and the short at offset 0x12 as a int16_t and so on, sometimes, just to fuck with developers the underlying data is TLV or has a variable length header so even the offsets have to be found by reading earlier data, and it does not overlay a struct in a sane way (RTP headers, looking at YOU, also .wav files)....

In this world explicitly declaring a pointer type is way more natural then inferring one.